# Sequence contains more than one element (linq sum)

Tags: asp.net, linq, webforms

I want to get the sum of the balance columns in the orders table and I used the following linq command, but I got an error:

> Sequence contains more than one element
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 101:            int term = Convert.ToInt32(Session["termId"]);
> Line 102:
> Line 103:            var course = Context.Courses.SingleOrDefault(s => s.TermId == term);
> Line 104:            double n3 = Context.Orders.Where(w=>w.CourseId ==  course.Id).Sum(o => o.balance);
> Line 105:            var config = Context.Configs.First(f=>f.Account_Id == id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are getting the error of line 103 (`SingleOrDefault`) and not line 104 (`Sum`).

`SingleOrDefault` throws an exception if there is more than one matching element in the sequence. (And return `default(Orders)` if there are none).

Perhaps you meant `FirstOrDefault` which just returning the first matching items and ignores the rest? (It will also run a tiny bit faster).